# Rails keeps looking for a non-existent gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I've replaced the gem mysql2 for a sqlite3 in development environment. However Rails keeps looking for it. I've tried to delete Gemfile.lock and it didn't work. I've also changed the database.yml file.

This is the error when I do **rails db:create**

*LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/gn09/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/arel-9.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb*

Comment: try  any / all of : 1) restarting the server 2) running bundle exec rails db:create 3) spring stop

Comment: did you find a solution? 2 people answered your question. be kind to leave feedback to the answers. That's how stackoverflow works.

Comment: @Yshmarov sorry I was sick, I will check it now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. replace gem in Gemfile

```
#gemfile.rb
gem 'sqlite3'
```

2. database.yml
   [something like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/excid3/railsconf-2020-actiontext/master/config/database.yml)
3. `bundle`
4. `bundle update` - update Gemfile.lock correctly
5. `rails db:create db:migrate`
6. `rails s`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did all the steps, and shows the same error.

LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/gn09/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/arel-9.0.0/lib/arel/visitors/mysql.rb

Comment: It turns out it was related to the rbenv. I uninstalled and installed again, as zawhtut suggested. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall ruby

```
rbenv uninstall 2.6.1
```

Then install again to get a fresh set of gems

```
rbenv uninstall 2.6.1
```

Then install bundler

```
gem install bunder -v '2.1.4'
```

Then

```
 bundle install
```

Comment: Thank you @zawhut, sorry for the delay. I did all the steps, now I have this error when I do rails server

-bash: /home/gn09/.rbenv/shims/rails: No such file or directory

Comment: After that I did gem install rails, and it worked.
Thank you very much!